# setting up service, got error "bash[29285]: /bin/bash: /usr/bin/code-server: No such file or directory"

Tags: server, bash, systemd, services

I am trying to set up code-server set up on a ubuntu 16.04 digitalocean droplet using this [this](https://medium.com/@malikbrowwn/how-to-host-vs-code-on-a-vps-using-coder-aka-code-server-d519767fb52c)
tutorial, but when I try to set up the service I get this output from systemctl status :

```
code-server.service - Visual Studio Code Server.

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/code-server.service; enabled; vendor  preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-05-11 22:33:45 UTC; 8s ago
  Process: 29285 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/code-server (code=exited, status=127) 
Main PID: 29285 (code=exited, status=127)

May 11 22:33:45 coder systemd[1]: Started Visual Studio Code Server..
May 11 22:33:45 coder bash[29285]: /bin/bash: /usr/bin/code-server: No such file or directory
May 11 22:33:45 coder systemd[1]: code-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
May 11 22:33:45 coder systemd[1]: code-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 11 22:33:45 coder systemd[1]: code-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have been through a dozens of SE threads trying to figure out the problem but I haven't found anything that works.

My .sh file is :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /home/chris/code-server/code-server /home/chris -p 8443 --password <redacted> --allow-http
```

and my service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description= Visual Studio Code Server.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/code-server.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# are these even necessary?
sudo systemctl start code-server
sudo systemctl status code-server
sudo systemctl enable code-server
```

This is my first time trying to do anything like this and I'm totally lost. I can copy the script location out of the service file and paste it onto the command line and it runs fine. I've tried solutions from several threads (so if my code looks a smidgen different from the tutorial, that's why), but I'm still getting the same error. I have no idea what I'm doing, so hopefully it's just something silly I'm missing, but any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I got it working.  Based on steeldriver's comment I made a copy of my code-server.sh file without the extension (so just code-server). It was found and everything started up and continues to run after the ssh session is ended. I just don't understand why, when the service file has the file extension in the execstart line.  I'd love if someone could explain that to me. I also don't understand why putting the binary in the bin folder and putting what's in the bin file now into the service file doesn't seem to work...this stuff makes my head hurt.

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like your service file actually has `ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/code-server` not `ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/code-server.sh` - please check the script name

Comment: Ya, I noticed that, but it definitely has the ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/code-server.sh in the service file. I figured maybe not showing the extension was a linux thing, but maybe there's a reason it's ignoring it?